# How to use JavaScript in my controller in asp.net MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, controller

I have a login page and want to show an alert when the user login was successful. but when I use JavaScript it doesn't work. in fact everything works just this javaScript doesn't work.

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult LogIn()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult LogIn(tblUser user)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var logData = UserBLL.LogInCheck(user);
            if (logData != null)
            {
                JavaScript("alert(Wellcome Dear Admin)");
                Session["user"] = "Admin";
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
        }

        return View();
    }
```

I don't know what to do!!!

Answer (score 1):

You can redirect the user by the javascript. So only return the Javascriptresult.

see the code below :-

```
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult LogIn(tblUser user)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var logData = UserBLL.LogInCheck(user);
                if (logData != null)
                {
                    Session["user"] = "Admin";
                    return JavaScript("alert(Wellcome Dear Admin); window.location.href = '" + Url.Action("Index", "Home") + "';");
                }
            }

            return View();
        }
```

Comment: did not worked. result is a page with just this text 
alert(Wellcome Dear Admin); window.location.href = '/';

Comment: @Heydar, how you calling the login post action from view?

Comment: my problem is There is a methode in asp.net mvc which is JavaScript and it's derived from JavaScriptResult class, i don't know how to post alert by using it in code .

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult LogIn(tblUser user)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var logData = UserBLL.LogInCheck(user);
                if (logData != null)
                {
                    Session["user"] = "Admin";
                    TempData["LoginSuccess"] = "1";
                }
            }

            return View();
        }
```

In cshtml:

```
@if (TempData["LoginSuccess"] != null)
{
    <script type="text/javascript">
        alert("Welcome Dear Admin!");
        window.location.href = '@Url.Action("Index", "Home")';
    </script>
}
```

Comment: I want to use JavaScript in code as before add any session and  if you see my code, the return code will redirect me out of current action. 
micorsoft give mvc a "JavaScript" methode which is from JavaScriptResult class and can be called directly as I do in my code. But I don't know how to use it !!!

Comment: Not sure what you mean but did you try the possible fix I provided?

Comment: no my brother, it seems that you didn't  understanded my problem,
There is a methode in asp.net mvc which is JavaScript and it's derived from JavaScriptResult class, i don't know how to post alert by using it in code .